# Exporting results of ArcMap Data Reviewer to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am new to the ArcMap 10.8.1 Data Reviewer extension and trying to use it to identify slivers.

I can produce a data reviewer table, but how do I download the results as a shapefile?

When I run the sliver check on polygons I get the message `“Unable to save Reviewer geometry for RecordID 1195 as its spatial reference is incompatible with Reviewer workspace spatial reference. Datum of geometry is not equal to Reviewer Dataset datum”` for all the records, but they are still written to the table.

These records do not show as selected in ArcMap and I can’t view the selected records which I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting all or selected results from the REVTABLEPOLY feature class? Aside from the SESSIOND and the LINKGUID, there isn't a whole lot of useful data in there, but you should be able to export from that FC.

[image]

[image]